# hourly cron task overlapping on 2 days

Tags: javascript, firebase, cron, schedule

I have to write some cron expressions from a firebase schedule function. As Google's servers aren't in the same timezone as me I will have to convert my existing expressions.
(from UTC+2 to UTC-5).
Here is an example of one of my expressions:
`0 9-17 * * 1-5` - from monday to friday at minute 0 from 9:00 to 17:00

How can I convert this so it will run at this time in UTC+2 when the server is in UTC-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because UTC+2 to UTC-5 is 7 hours backwards you should take the time 7 hours backwards:

```
0 2-10 * * 1-5
```

Comment: Thank you I was going the wrong way (+7 instead)

Answer (score 0):

When we look at the Firebase Schedule Function documentation found documented here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

we find a section called **Write a scheduled function**.  In there we find that when we code:

```
functions.pubsub.schedule("<CRON String">)
```

we can add a `timeZone` setting. For example:

```
functions.pubsub.schedule("<CRON String">).timeZone('America/New_York')
```

What this means to us is that we can set a specific time zone against which our CRON intervals will be evaluated.  According to the documentation, the default time zone is `utc`.

Comment: That's what I did too at first. But for an unknown reason the timezone isn't applied and us-central1 is still the timezone of execution. (in the google cloud scheduler it is the new timezone). In the documentation the default is America/Los_Angeles